# Bash script terminates after loop

Tags: bash, loops, getopts

I am experimenting with `getopts` in bash. I am adding the following snippet as an example.

**script-setup.sh**

```
set -e
...
package_version="v1.1.0"
grafana_username=""
grafana_password=""

subcommand=$1; shift
while [ ! -z "$subcommand" ]; do  
    case "$subcommand" in 
        package_version)
            package_version=$1; shift; echo "Package_version:::: $package_version"
            shift $((OPTIND -1))
            ;;
        grafana_username)
            grafana_username=$1; shift; echo "Grafana_username::: $grafana_username"
            shift $((OPTIND -1))
            ;;
        grafana_password)
            grafana_password=$1; shift; echo "Grafana_password::: $grafana_password"
            shift $((OPTIND -1));
            ;;
    esac
    subcommand=$1; shift;
done     

touch sample.xml 

echo "Creating a file"
echo "Package version chosen:  $package_version"
...
```

### Expected Result:

```
$ ./script-setup.sh package_version "v1.3.0" grafana_username "admin" grafana_password "abcd"                                                                                                                                 
Package_version:::: v1.3.0
Grafana_username::: admin
Grafana_password::: abcd
Creating a file
Package version chosen:  v1.3.0
```

### Actual Result:

```
$ ./script-setup.sh package_version "v1.3.0" grafana_username "admin" grafana_password "abcd"                                                                                                                                
Package_version:::: v1.3.0
Grafana_username::: admin
Grafana_password::: abcd
```

As we see, in the above case: the script fails to create a file viz. `sample.xml` and fails to execute the last two `echo` statements. This is a confusing behavior according to me, or maybe I am wrong.

The `loop` in the bash script was replaced by `for` loop, but still nothing changed.

### Bash version:

```
$ bash -version                                                                                                                                                                                                                         1 ↵
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)
```

Comment: Where are you using `getopts`?

Comment: The first debugging step for shell scripts is to put `set -x` at the beginning. It will then show all the commands as they're being executed, so you can see what's happening.

Comment: Are you running the script with the `-e` option? It may be getting an error and exiting after the loop.

Comment: Have a look at https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035 and don't use getopts unless you really intend to publish your work for the outside world

Comment: Why are you using `shift $((OPTIND -1))`? That's what you'd use after a `getopts` loop (to remove the just-processed option arguments), but there's no `getopts` loop here.

Comment: You are right @Barmar ! I am using `-e` option here, as soon as I changed the mode to `-x` I am able to see it move through to the next step after the loop. There is one more block above the loop which uses `getopts`, removed it for the sake of brevity.

Comment: Thank you @kvantour ! Duly noted! You are right, it makes sense.